# Showing that $A+\epsilon I$ is non-singular for $0<|\epsilon|<r$

Tags: linear-algebra

How to approach this problem:

> Let $A\in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$. Show that there exists a real
>    number $r>0$ so that $A+\epsilon I$ is non-singular, when $\epsilon\in
>  \mathbb{R}$, $0<|\epsilon|<r$

Thank you for any help.

Comment: See [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/189750/1508) for a slightly less rigorous version of this question. (I don't know whether it should count as a duplicate.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the function $p $ that sends  $\epsilon $ to  $det (A+\epsilon I) $.

$p $ is a polynomial of degree  $n $. Hence it can be zero for at most  $n $  values of  $\epsilon $. Now choose $r>0 $ to have magnitude less than all of magnitudes of the non-zero roots of $p $

Comment: Thank you for your help. Understood :)