# $\overline{ \{\det > 0\} } = \{\det\ge 0\}$ for $\det$ the determinant function

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A = (a_{ij})_{1\le i,j\le n}$ be a square matrix with real entries, with determinant $\det(A) = 0$. To show that for every $\epsilon> 0$ there exists $A'= (a'_{ij})$ another matrix, $|a'_{ij} - a_{ij}|< \epsilon$ for all $i, j$,  and $\det A'>0$.

Notes:

1. Consider the general case of a function $f\colon X \to \mathbb{R}$. Clearly we have $\overline{ \{f>0\}}\subseteq \{f\ge 0\}$.  The inclusion may be strict. For instance, consider the polynomial function $f(x,y) = x^2 y$. Now, the only issue is whether $\{f= 0\} \subseteq \overline{ \{ f>0\}}$. This is the case when $X$ manifold,  $f$ smooth and $d f\ne 0$ on $\{f=0\}$. ( the hypersurface $\{f=0\}$ is then non-singular).
2. The similar question "? $\overline{ \{ f < 0 \}} = \{ f\le 0\}$ ?" may be asked. If $f$ is a homogenous polynomial, it is equivalent to the previous one.  Also, observe that $\overline{ \{ f < 0 \}} = \{ f\le 0\}$ is equivalent to: $\{f>0\}$ is the interior of $\{f\ge 0\}$.
3. One could consider the original question $\det \colon X\to \mathbb{R}$, where now $X$ is not the full $M_{n\times n}$ but a certain (affine) subspace (for instance (bordered) symmetric determinants).

Thank you for your interest! Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you can choose $A' = A + \epsilon I$, compare https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1618027/42969.

Comment: For (2), just use the previous lemmas on $-f$.

Comment: @Martin R: If you expand $\det (A+ \epsilon I)$, it will be $\epsilon^m( c+ c'\epsilon + \cdots)$. It may be that $m$ is even, but $c< 0$. Some care is needed.

Comment: $\det$ has no local maxima or minima. I'll call $A\oplus B$ the block diagonal matrix with $A$ first and $B$ second. Consider an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP=T\oplus B$, with $\det B\ne0$ and $T$ upper triangular and nilpotent (you can do this in many ways, e.g. let $\mu_A(t)=t^k f(t)$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$, with $f(0)\ne0$, and consider the restrictions to $\ker(A^k)$ and $\ker(f(A))$). Call $L_\pm=\operatorname{diag}(\pm1,1,\cdots,1)\oplus 0$ and consider $G_{\epsilon,\pm}=A+\varepsilon PL_\pm P^{-1}\to A$. We have that $G_{\epsilon,\pm}=\pm\epsilon^u \det B$.

Comment: This proves absence of maxima or minima at $\det A=0$. If $\det A\ne0$, or more generally if $\dim\ker A\le1$, then notice that $d_A\det$ is the map $H\mapsto \operatorname{tr}(\operatorname{adj}(A)H)$, which is a non-zero map.

Comment: @Sassatelli Giulio: Thank you for your interest!  Would you want to write up an answer, it would be useful for everybody.

Comment: @orangeskid No thanks, I'd rather not. Anybody who wants to write it and take the points can.

Comment: @Sassatelli Giulio:Well, you had some mighty good observations, I guess we'll just read them in the comments. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A= QR$ be the [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) of the given matrix. $Q$ is orthogonal (so that $\det Q = \pm 1$) and $R$ an upper triangular matrix.

Since $\det A = 0$, some diagonal elements of $R$ are zero. By replacing the zero diagonal elements with $\pm \epsilon$ we can achieve that $\det R$ is positive (if $\det Q = 1$) or negative (if $\det Q = -1$) for all $\epsilon > 0$. Let's call the resulting matrix $R_\epsilon$.

Then $\det(A_\epsilon) > 0$ for $A_\epsilon = Q R_\epsilon$, and the coefficients of $A_\epsilon$ depend continuously on $\epsilon$.

If $A$ is also *symmetric* then one can work with its [eigenvalue decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Real_symmetric_matrices) $A=Q D Q^T$ instead , where $Q$ is orthogonal and $D$ is a diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues of $A$. Similar as a above, this gives a *symmetric* matrix $A_\epsilon = Q D_\epsilon Q^T$ with $\det(A_\epsilon) > 0$ for $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Escape ray found, thanks!

Comment: If the matrix $A$ is symmetric, can you get a symmetric ray?

Comment: @orangeskid: What is a “symmetric ray”?

Comment: You showed that $\det>0$ on a ray $A+ \epsilon M$, for $\epsilon > 0$. So if $A$ is symmetric, $M$ should be also symmetric ( the problem  about $\det$ restricted on the symmetric matrices).

Comment: @orangeskid: A real symmetric matrix can be written as $A = Q D Q^T$ with a diagonal matrix $D$ (the [eigendecomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Real_symmetric_matrices)). Then you can apply the above pertubation to $D$ instead of $R$.

Comment: Oh, great, that does it!  Thank you so much!