# Matrix inverse of $A + \epsilon I$, where $A$ is invertible

Tags: matrices, inverse, perturbation-theory

Let $A$ be a square invertible matrix, and $\epsilon$ a small positive quantity. To first-order in $\epsilon$, what is the inverse of $A + \epsilon I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix?

Comment: You can probably do some series expansion. Like Taylor of $1/(1+x^{-1})$ or something of the sort.

Comment: Hint: geometric series.

Comment: @NateEldredge The formula I typically see is for the inverse of $I + \epsilon A$, where you can apply the geometric series directly. Right after posting I found a way to apply that result in this case.

Comment: Yep, factor out an $A$.

Comment: Similar question asked long ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189750/does-mathbf-a-epsilon-mathbf-i-1-always-exist-why

Comment: @StubbornAtom That raises the question, is there a similar approximation if $A$ is not invertible?

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do it right after posting.

$$(A + \varepsilon I)^{- 1} = A^{- 1} A (A + \varepsilon I)^{- 1} = A^{- 1} (I
+ \varepsilon A^{- 1})^{- 1} \approx A^{- 1} (I - \varepsilon A^{- 1})$$

Comment: Or just check $(A^{-1}-\epsilon A^{-2})(A+\epsilon I) = I - \epsilon^2 A^{-2} = I + O(\epsilon^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it as

$\left((I+\varepsilon A^{-1})A\right)^{-1}=A^{-1}\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty A^{-n}\varepsilon^n= \sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty A^{-n-1}\varepsilon^n,$

where $A^0=I$. ((I+B) is invertible if $B$ has norm, as a linear operator, less than 1, so for $\varepsilon$ small this works).