# Invertibility of $(\textbf{A}^T\textbf{A}+\epsilon \textbf{I})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

I'm given a problem:

$\sigma_1 \geq \sigma_2 \geq ... \geq \sigma_r$ are the nonzero singular values of $\textbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$. If $\epsilon \neq 0$ is a real scalar, s.t. $|\epsilon| < \sigma^{2}_r$, show that $(\textbf{A}^T\textbf{A}+\epsilon \textbf{I})$ is invertible.

I found the resources [Why is $A^TA$ invertible if $A$ has independent columns?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1840801/why-is-ata-invertible-if-a-has-independent-columns) and [Matrix inverse of $A + \epsilon I$, where $A$ is invertible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2925551/matrix-inverse-of-a-epsilon-i-where-a-is-invertible)

But I'm not sure how useful they are. The first is in the case where A has independent columns, which is not necessarily true here, and the second presumes A is invertible. I believe that $\textbf{A}^T\textbf{A}$ is invertible by definition, but I'm not sure if I can just plug $\textbf{A}^T\textbf{A}$ in everywhere that post uses A and follow through. That also wouldn't help me understand the problem, just blindly substitute into a solution.

Can anyone help me understand WHY $(\textbf{A}^T\textbf{A}+\epsilon \textbf{I})$ is invertible? And/or point me in the right direction to construct a proof of it?

Comment: Just a thought, you can diagonalize $A^TA$, so it shouldnt be too hard to analyze everything after a suitable change of basis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write out $A$ in its SVD, $A=U\Sigma V^T$. Then we have

$$A^TA+\epsilon I = V\Sigma^2 V^T+\epsilon I = V\Sigma^2V^T+\epsilon VV^T = V(\Sigma^2+\epsilon I)V^T.$$
From this, we have that the eigenvalues are exactly $\sigma_i^2+\epsilon$ for $i=1\dots r$ and $\epsilon$ for $i=r+1\dots n$. These are all nonzero, so the matrix is invertible.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a straightforward way to find the limit of $(\textbf{A}^T\textbf{A}+\epsilon \textbf{I})^{−1}\textbf{A}^T$ as $\epsilon$ goes to 0? Obviously this reduces to $(\textbf{A}^T\textbf{A})^{-1}\textbf{A}^T$, but I'm not sure where to go from here without specific values for A

Answer (score 1):

You can show that $A^\top A$ is positive semi-definite (specifically, that it has nonnegative eigenvalues $\sigma_1^2, \ldots, \sigma_r^2, 0, \ldots, 0$).

[It is not always invertible. Specifically, if some of its eigenvalues are zero, then it is not invertible.]

Knowing this fact about $A^\top A$, can you explicitly write down the eigenvalues of $A^\top A + \epsilon I$? What values of $\epsilon$ make this matrix invertible or non-invertible?

Comment: Wouldn't the eigenvalues just be $\sigma_{1}^{2}+\epsilon , \sigma_{2}^{2}+\epsilon , ...\sigma_{r}^{2}+\epsilon$, with trailing eigenvalues of $\epsilon$ if $\textbf{A}^T\textbf{A}$ was not invertible?